# How to convert an Array List of objects to Json

Tags: java, json, playframework

I have an `ArrayList` which I want to transform into a JSON array of objects. How can I transform it?

Array is of type `Kunde`:

```
public class Kunde {
    private String knr;
    private String name1;
    private String name2;
    private String anrede;
    private String strasse;
    private String plz;
    private String ort;
    private String erfdat;
    private String telefon;
    private String fax;
    private String handy;
    private String lastbes;
    private String email;
    private String land;
```

for each member variable there is a getter and a setter.

I store it like this:

```
   List<Kunde> Kunden = new ArrayList<Kunde>();
```

My JSON should look like this:

```
   { 
     "kunden": [
       {"name1": "hans", "name2": "peter"}, 
       {...} 
     ]
   }
```

Comment: Is it really a duplicate if it's Play Framework specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play comes with `play-json` module which can do it. You might have to create a wrapping class to output the `kunden` root node:

```
public class Kunden {
  private List<Kunde> kunden;
  // getter and setter
}

Kunden root = new Kunden();
kunden.setKunden(...);

JsonNode rootNode = Json.toJson(root);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(node);
```

Note that `ObjectMapper` is used to pretty print.

See the official Play Framework 2.6.X docs: [Mapping Java objects to JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaJsonActions#Mapping-Java-objects-to-JSON).

Comment: works absolute fine!

Answer (score -2):

Try to do something like this

```
ArrayList<Kundle> list = new ArrayList<Kundle>();
    list.add("yo");
    list.add("yo");
    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```